# Use of logical_and with list of lists

Tags: python, numpy, boolean

Suppose I have the following two lists:

```
l = [[], [1]]
m = [0, 1]
```

If I check to see if elements are in a list:

```
>>> np.array(m[1]) == 1
True
>>> 1 in np.array(l)[1]
True
```

This works as expected.

However, if I use the numpy `logical_and` operator, this fails:

```
>>> np.logical_and(np.array(m) == 1, 1 in np.array(l))
array([False, False])
```

Why are both positions in the array being evaluated as `False`?

The goal is to evaluate lists of these forms element-wise. And, as per the documentation, `np.logical_and` is used to "Compute the truth value of x1 AND x2 element-wise."

Since l is a list of lists, I am using the `in` operator to test the element-wise comparisons.

Thus, I expect the output of `>>> np.logical_and(np.array(m) == 1, 1 in np.array(l))`

to be

```
array([False, True])
```

after all, `[1]` is just an element in `np.array(l)`:

```
>>> for i in np.array(l):
...     print(i)
...
[]
[1]
```

Comment: You dropped the `[1]`s. Was that deliberate?

Comment: 1 in np.array(l)
    Out[30]: False

Comment: If it was deliberate, then you should look at the individual outputs of `np.array(m) == 1` and `1 in np.array(l)` before bringing `np.logical_and` into the picture. If it was an accident, then this question should be closed as occurring due to a typo.

Comment: Didn't drop anything, AFAIK. One list is a list of lists and the other a list of integers. Not sure why this got down voted. I am try to do comparisons list element by list element.

Comment: Why do you expect `1 in np.array(l)` to be True. 1 is not in that array. `[1]` is in that array but `1` is not same as `[1]` The first is a number, the second is a list.

Comment: It might be my naïveté at work, but since `np.logical_and` iterates element-wise through the arrays being passed to it, and since one the the elements in the list `l` is `[1]` and since `1 in [1]` is `True`, then I would think this would evaluate the same when the 2nd elements in the 2-arrays were evaluated in `np.logical_and`. If not, then I obviously need another method for doing my element-wise comparisions.

Comment: Doesn't work:
`>>> (np.logical_and(np.array(m) == 1, [1] in np.array(l)))
array([False, False])` ... plus, while `[1]` is that element (I fully agree!!), the test is whether 1 is in the list `[1]`, which it is. Not if the list is in the list.

Comment: I see your point. Maybe you can flatten that list. `import itertools` then  `1 in np.array(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(l)))` returns True

Comment: ` [1] in np.array(l)` evaluates to False is because, numpy assigns a datatype - `dtype=object` to all the elements in this case. And this object is not equal to python list

Comment: Thanks, that does work and that makes sense, but the empty lists then vanish, which is a problem. I will shove `None` intto the empty list as a placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

So just analyzing your code

```
np.array(m) == 1 
>>> [False  True]
1 in np.array(l)
>>> False
```

You're basically comparing **False** with **[False True]**

**Update**

If you want the output to be [False True] then you should use logical_or instead.

Comment: @bhaskarc already answered my question. I am using `logical_or` to evaluate other conditions, and was gertting similar quirky errors. Turns out I didn't realize the elements were of type: `dtype=object`.